# Is the AST/ALT ratio a valid method to detect hepatitis C and cirrhosis?

Tags: hepatitis, ratio

I am currently studying the [AST/ALT ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AST/ALT_ratio) and its ability to detect hepatitis and cirrhosis.

I read some articles about this topic and they all seem to consider this ratio quite useful, but I also noticed this study saying the opposite: "[AST/ALT Ratio ≥1 is not diagnostic of cirrhosis in patients with chronic hepatitis C](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1018888021118)" (Reedy et al, *Digestive Diseases and Sciences*, 1998)

What is the current state of the AST/ALT ratio?
Is it currently used in clinical settings?
Is it considered reliable by phyisicians?

Thanks